# Modifying a Biztalk message from custom code

Tags: biztalk

Disclaimer: I am a complete biztalk newbie.

I need to be able to read and potentially edit 4 nodes in a biztalk message; preferably this needs to be done from a c# helper class as I am making a service call and also have unit tests written for this.

I already have this class wired up and it works with the XLANGMessage class, the problem I am running into is at this point in the orchestration the message is a Schema based type and doesn't seem to have any way for me to modify it.

I've done some reading and found a few ideas but have not been able to confirm if any of these can work from custom code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass messages into and out of C# helper classes easily.  The simplest way is just to treat input parameters and return values as of type System.Xml.XmlDocument.  The XLANG/s engine will safely cast back and forth from the XLANGMessage type to XmlDocument.

As you are essentially creating a "new" instance of the message (messages are immutable in BizTalk), the call to your helper class needs to be performed in a Message Assignment shape, with the outer Construct shape constructing the copy of your original message.

```
public static XmlDocument UpdateMyMessage(XmlDocument sourceMessage)
{
  /* Do stuff to your Message here */

  return sourceMessage;
}
```

A best-practice to consider is to declare all your C# helper methods as Static.  This will avoid any issues with de/serialisation of your helper class during dehydration.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that the engine handles conversion between XLANGMessage and XmlDocument, I will be able to clean up the code I have quite nicely knowing that.  Also in the end it was the Message Assignment Shape I was missing.

Comment: Any possibility of keeping the convenience of this method for faking mutability without using the generic XmlDocument type? I need to construct a message by using a map first, and then modify nodes in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

1 write a map to transform the incoming message to the desired type

or

2 write something like this in your helper component to transform the message

public XmlDocument TransformMessage(XLANGMessage message)

Then pass the result document to a biztalk message in a [message assignment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa561718.aspx) shape.

responseMessage = xmlDocument;

You may get better performance if you [pass streams instead of messages around](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/paolos/archive/2010/04/08/how-to-boost-message-transformations-using-the-xslcompiledtransform-class-extended.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Are BizTalk messages immutable?

Generally speaking they are however, by creating a “corrective” orchestration and using a pass by reference option on the incoming message parameter, an existing message can be modified.